# Need help for setting up rest client and resource class for uploading a csv file to REST service

Tags: java, rest

I try to build a REST service to handle csv file uploaded by the user, use “Advanced Rest Client” to upload a csv file and send a request using POST method to the resource class I created, set up a check point at the beginning inside the method of the resource class want to make sure it can get to the check point when I send the request from “Advanced Rest Client”,  can’t make it work, getting error,  can’t figure out what would be correct set up for both the “Advanced Rest Client” and annotation at the resource class and it’s method, please help.

The way I set up on “Advanced Rest Client”

1. "POST" method is selected
2. Headers: Accept: application/json Content-Type: multipart/form-data
3. Payload: (Files tab been selected)
       (a csv been picked) The file name field been enter a file name “file”

**My resource class:**

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
@Path("/")
public class SampleResource {

@GET
@Path("/getVersion")
public String getVer() {

    String version = this.servletConfig.getInitParameter("ServiceVersion");

    if (version == null) {
        version = "1.0.0";
    }
    return version;
}

@POST
@Path("/leveloverride")
@Consumes("MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA")  
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public Response handleSellerOverride(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream 

fileInputString, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInputDetails) throws Exception {
        Map<String,List<String>> mapHeaderFields = headers.getRequestHeaders(); //has check point
        String fileRequstId = mapHeaderFields.get("FileRequestId").get(0);  //Probably use file name as the Request Id more reasonable.

        System.out.print(fileRequstId);
//      SellerLevelOverrideResponse response = sloService.processRequest(file, fileRequstId);
        return null;
    }
}
```

URL:
POST Method: http://localhost:8080/spstools/sampleResource/v1/leveloverride
GET Method: http://localhost:8080/spstools/sampleResource/v1/getVersion?=

(Tested the get method url is working fine, post method getting error like below)

```
09:45:51.044 [DefaultThreadPool-7] ERROR c.s.j.c.s.component.ProviderServices - The class org.ebayopensource.ginger.server.internal.container.jersey.COSChainingFilter is not assignable to the class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter. This class is ignored.
09:45:51.301 [DefaultThreadPool-7] ERROR c.s.j.s.s.c.servlet.SpringServlet - Exception occurred when intialization
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.text.ParseException: End of header
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:230) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:197) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.addConsumes(IntrospectionModeller.java:158) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.workOutSubResourceMethodsList(IntrospectionModeller.java:341) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:126) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:745) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1522) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1295) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117) ~[jersey-spring-1.8.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160) [servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.ebayopensource.ginger.server.container.GingerServletShell.doInit(GingerServletShell.java:101) [ebay-jaxrs-2.1.2-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.ebayopensource.ginger.spring.server.container.GingerSpringServletShell.init(GingerSpringServletShell.java:37) [spring-jaxrs-2.1.2-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0-45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0-45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0-45]
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: End of header
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.getNextCharacter(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:219) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.next(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:184) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderListAdapter.next(HttpHeaderListAdapter.java:102) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.nextSeparator(HttpHeaderReader.java:112) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:90) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$2.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:304) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$2.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:302) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readList(HttpHeaderReader.java:465) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readMediaTypes(HttpHeaderReader.java:309) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:224) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
09:45:51.310 [DefaultThreadPool-7] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] - StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.text.ParseException: End of header
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:230) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:197) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.addConsumes(IntrospectionModeller.java:158) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.workOutSubResourceMethodsList(IntrospectionModeller.java:341) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:126) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:745) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1522) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1295) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117) ~[jersey-spring-1.8.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.ebayopensource.ginger.server.container.GingerServletShell.doInit(GingerServletShell.java:101) ~[ebay-jaxrs-2.1.2-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.ebayopensource.ginger.spring.server.container.GingerSpringServletShell.init(GingerSpringServletShell.java:37) ~[spring-jaxrs-2.1.2-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0-45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0-45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0-45]
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: End of header
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.getNextCharacter(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:219) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.next(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:184) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderListAdapter.next(HttpHeaderListAdapter.java:102) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.nextSeparator(HttpHeaderReader.java:112) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:90) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$2.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:304) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$2.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:302) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readList(HttpHeaderReader.java:465) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readMediaTypes(HttpHeaderReader.java:309) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:224) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
09:45:51.319 [DefaultThreadPool-7] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[GingerServlet] - Allocate exception for servlet GingerServlet
java.text.ParseException: End of header
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.getNextCharacter(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:219) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.next(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:184) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderListAdapter.next(HttpHeaderListAdapter.java:102) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.nextSeparator(HttpHeaderReader.java:112) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:90) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$2.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:304) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$2.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:302) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readList(HttpHeaderReader.java:465) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readMediaTypes(HttpHeaderReader.java:309) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:224) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:197) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.addConsumes(IntrospectionModeller.java:158) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.workOutSubResourceMethodsList(IntrospectionModeller.java:341) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:126) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:745) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1522) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1295) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117) ~[jersey-spring-1.8.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556) ~[jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.ebayopensource.ginger.server.container.GingerServletShell.doInit(GingerServletShell.java:101) ~[ebay-jaxrs-2.1.2-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.ebayopensource.ginger.spring.server.container.GingerSpringServletShell.init(GingerSpringServletShell.java:37) ~[spring-jaxrs-2.1.2-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0-45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0-45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0-45]
```

Comment: `@Consumes("MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA")` should be `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`... no `"`s

Comment: Yes, take out "" will make it work, thanks a lot.